# django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: [''] on Datefiled - Resolvido

Tags: django

My friends!

I completely edited the forum, since one of the scenarios no longer exists

The goal is to allow registration with the empty date form, think like a family tree, if I don't know when he died, I leave it blank, or even when he was born.

Legend:
`data_de_nascimento` is Birth date
`data_de_falecimento` is death date

Obs .: The information is being registered in the table, even reporting the error

My models:

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import date
from django.utils.dateparse import (parse_date, parse_datetime, parse_duration, parse_time)
from multiselectfield import MultiSelectField

# Create your models here.

class Familia(models.Model):

    primeiro_nome = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    ultimo_nome = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    GENDER_CHOICES = (
        ('M', 'Masculino'),
        ('F','Feminino')
    )
    genero = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=GENDER_CHOICES)
    data_de_nascimento = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    local_do_nascimento = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    data_de_falecimento = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    local_do_falecimento = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    foto = models.ImageField(upload_to='arvore', blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)

    @property
    def foto_url(self):
        if self.foto and hasattr(self.foto, 'url'):
            return self.foto.url
        else:
            return '#'

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'db_genealogia'
```

```py
@login_required(login_url='/login/')
def set_familia(request):

    primeiro_nome = request.POST.get ('primeiro_nome')
    ultimo_nome = request.POST.get('ultimo_nome')
    data_de_nascimento = request.POST.get('data_de_nascimento', None)
    local_do_nascimento = request.POST.get('local_do_nascimento', None)
    data_de_falecimento = request.POST.get('data_de_falecimento', None)
    local_do_falecimento = request.POST.get('local_do_falecimento', None)
    genero = request.POST.get('genero')
    file = request.FILES.get('file', None)
    user = request.user
    print(ultimo_nome)
    print(genero)
    print(data_de_nascimento)
    print(file)
    familia_id = request.POST.get('familia_id')
    if familia_id:
        familia = Familia.objects.get(id=familia_id)
        if user == familia.user:
            familia.primeiro_nome = primeiro_nome
            familia.ultimo_nome = ultimo_nome
            familia.local_do_nascimento = local_do_nascimento
            familia.data_de_nascimento = data_de_nascimento
            familia.data_de_falecimento = data_de_falecimento
            familia.local_do_falecimento = local_do_falecimento
            familia.genero = genero
            if file:
                familia.foto = file
            familia.save()
    else:
        familia = Familia.objects.create(user=user, primeiro_nome=primeiro_nome, ultimo_nome=ultimo_nome, data_de_nascimento=data_de_nascimento,
                                    local_do_nascimento=local_do_nascimento,data_de_falecimento=data_de_falecimento,
                                    local_do_falecimento=local_do_falecimento, foto=file, genero=genero)
    url = '/familia/detail/{}/'.format(familia.id)
    return redirect(url)
```

My URL:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from arvores import views
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import static
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
from . import settings
from django.views.generic import RedirectView

    urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('login/', views.login_user),
    path('login/submit', views.submit_login),
    path('familia/user/', views.list_user_familias),
    path('familia/all/', views.list_all_familias),
    path('familia/detail/<slug:id>/', views.familia_detail),
    path('familia/register/', views.register_familia),
    path('familia/register/submit', views.set_familia),
    path('familia/delete/<slug:id>/', views.delete_familia),
    path('logout/', views.logout_user),
    path('', RedirectView.as_view(url='familia/all/'))
]

    urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Template:

```html
<p>{{ familia.description }}</p>
<p><b>Nome Completo.: </b>{{ familia.primeiro_nome }}&nbsp{{ familia.ultimo_nome}}</p> 
    {% if familia.data_de_nascimento %}                
<p><b>Data de Nascimento.: </b>{{ familia.data_de_nascimento|default_if_none:"nothing" }}</p> 
    {% else %}
<p></p>           
    {% endif %}
<p><b>local de nascimento: </b>{{ familia.local_do_nascimento }}</p>
<p><b>Data de Falecimento.: </b>{{ familia.data_de_falecimento|default_if_none:"nothing" }}</p> 
<p><b>local de nascimento: </b>{{ familia.local_do_falecimento }}</p>
```

Traceback message:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Projeto_Python\virtuallenv\genealogia\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "D:\Projeto_Python\virtuallenv\genealogia\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "D:\Projeto_Python\virtuallenv\genealogia\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "D:\Projeto_Python\virtuallenv\genealogia\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py", line 21, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Projeto_Python\projeto_genealogia\genealogia\arvores\views.py", line 85, in set_familia
    familia = Familia.objects.create(user=user, primeiro_nome=primeiro_nome, ultimo_nome=ultimo_nome, data_de_nascimento=data_de_nascimento,
  File "D:\Projeto_Python\virtuallenv\genealogia\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Projeto_Python\virtuallenv\genealogia\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 433, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "D:\Projeto_Python\virtuallenv\genealogia\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 745, in save
    self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert,
  File "D:\Projeto_Python\virtuallenv\genealogia\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 782, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(
  File "D:\Projeto_Python\virtuallenv\genealogia\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 887, in _save_table
    results = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, returning_fields, raw)
  File "D:\Projeto_Python\virtuallenv\genealogia\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 924, in _do_insert
    return manager._insert(
  File "D:\Projeto_Python\virtuallenv\genealogia\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Projeto_Python\virtuallenv\genealogia\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1204, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
  File "D:\Projeto_Python\virtuallenv\genealogia\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1390, in execute_sql
    for sql, params in self.as_sql():
  File "D:\Projeto_Python\virtuallenv\genealogia\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1333, in as_sql
    value_rows = [
  File "D:\Projeto_Python\virtuallenv\genealogia\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1334, in <listcomp>
    [self.prepare_value(field, self.pre_save_val(field, obj)) for field in fields]
  File "D:\Projeto_Python\virtuallenv\genealogia\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1334, in <listcomp>
    [self.prepare_value(field, self.pre_save_val(field, obj)) for field in fields]
  File "D:\Projeto_Python\virtuallenv\genealogia\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1275, in prepare_value
    value = field.get_db_prep_save(value, connection=self.connection)
  File "D:\Projeto_Python\virtuallenv\genealogia\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 821, in get_db_prep_save
    return self.get_db_prep_value(value, connection=connection, prepared=False)
  File "D:\Projeto_Python\virtuallenv\genealogia\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1220, in get_db_prep_value
    value = self.get_prep_value(value)
  File "D:\Projeto_Python\virtuallenv\genealogia\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1215, in get_prep_value
    return self.to_python(value)
  File "D:\Projeto_Python\virtuallenv\genealogia\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1187, in to_python
    raise exceptions.ValidationError(

Exception Type: ValidationError at /familia/register/submit
Exception Value: ['']
```

Tshoot done:

I already made a change in the models page, for the format below and the only change was in the admin screen, the error continued

`data_de_nascimento = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True, default=date(1111, 11, 11)`

ISSUE RESOLVED:

After changing the View, I completed the change in the template:

data_de_nascimento = request.POST['data_de_nascimento']
    if not data_de_nascimento:
            data_de_nascimento = None

**Data de Nascimento.:**{{ familia.data_de_nascimento|default_if_none:''  }}

Comment: Please show us your tracebacks from the terminal/cmd.

Comment: My friend, I will tell you, I opened this forum, before going to sleep, and spent the night reflecting, this morning I realized that I was configuring the wrong template, my error regarding the image, it was solved, however I still have problems with the date.

Internal Server Error: /familia/register/submit
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Projeto_Python\virtuallenv\genealogia\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1187, in to_python
    raise exceptions.ValidationError(
django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ['']

Comment: Please edit the question with complete traceback.

Comment: check now please.

Comment: I managed to get around as follows, in my View:  

data_de_nascimento = request.POST['data_de_nascimento']
    if not data_de_nascimento:
            data_de_nascimento = None

The result in the application is None, if anyone knows how for 100% Null I appreciate it, otherwise it will become an ugly table